# how to classify intermediate value

Tags: r, dplyr, case, mutate

I have quite enough extensive dataset

```
> dput(mmt[,14:16])
structure(list(MM_score = c(265, 87.5, 242.5, 200, 230, 190, 
72.5, 97.5, 187.5, 27.5, 80, 125, 55, 87.5, 70, 105, 112.5, 0, 
15, 92.5, 185, 265, 165, 235, 92.5, 110, 72.5, 242.5, 240, 130, 
140, 282.5, 75, 147.5, 37.5, 175, 35, 127.5, 105, 42.5, 265, 
257.5, 45, 75, 102.5, 65, 115, 75, 90, 192.5, 35, 87.5, 175, 
147.5, 82.5, 172.5, 137.5, 92.5, 92.5, 120, 120, 152.5, 140, 
135, 77.5, 62.5, 115, 110, 225, 60, 95, 50, 427.5, 80, 172.5, 
215, 135, 65, 112.5, 152.5, 110, 295, 105, 37.5, 115, 52.5, 80, 
100, 310, 65, 320, 260, 92.5, 165, 0, 125), cut_off = c(131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 
131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125, 131.328125), 
    dv = c(79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 79.6546436392096, 
    79.6546436392096)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -96L))
```

I am interested in categorizing the MM_score variable in a way that:

1. if it has a value above (mean + a standard deviation), this will result as an **high score**
2. if it is a value below (mean - a standard deviation), this will result as a **high score**
3. and if it is an intermediate value (included within the extreme in the brackets), this will result as an **intermediate score**

I have used the following code:

```
 dat%>%
mutate(MM_levels = case_when(MM_score < (cut_off + dv)  ~ 'LMM',
                               MM_score > (cut_off - dv) ~ 'HMM', 
               (cut_off - dv) >= MM_score & MM_score <= (cut_off + dv) ~ 'IMM')
```

but I am not sure whether it returns the idea of intermediate that I have. How does it look like to you?

Thanks

Comment: Have you swapped `'LMM'` and `'HMM'`? Why not 'high', 'low', 'intermediate' instead of abbreviations?

Comment: As I understand your description, intermediate is whatever is not covered by low or high. In that case, leave it to the default of `case_when`: `TRUE ~ IMM`. Alternatively, consider {dplyr}'s `between`.

Comment: Could you please provide some examples of this between function that might fit to my case?